# Moving image with it's touch event in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-canvas, android-imageview

I am trying to make that one image is moving automatically in whole screen as per resolution of mobile device. Now, i want its click or touch event. I have refereed many things but couldn't find any relevant answer. Is there any example related it so i can refer in android.

Comment: `moving automatically` means are you using `Handler` for it?? And you can implement `onTouch()` event for it.

Comment: A lot of scrollable stuff has headers and footers built in so you can put your own elements there if you implement them.

Comment: I have no idea about it. Can you tell me how to use it? @PiyushGupta

Comment: Can you elaborate please or can you give me some reference example for what you about to say? @G_V

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to move image.I am using it and it is working fine for me.

```
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Touch implements OnTouchListener {

    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        // Dump touch event to log
        dumpEvent(event);

        // Handle touch events here...
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    // ...
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

    /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE", "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }
        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }
        sb.append("]");
    }

    /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
}
```

note->
    from your activity attach this listener by doing 
      imageview.setOnTouchListener(new Touch());

Comment: Can you tell me how can i implement this class into my MainActivity ? @SANJAYGUPTA

Comment: Simple copy paste this class in you package and use  imageview.setOnTouchListener(new Touch()); in your oncreate method

Comment: Thanks for your help but, i have done but image is not moving. @SANJAYGUPTA

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    // these matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    // we can be in one of these 3 states
    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private static final int DRAG = 1;
    private static final int ZOOM = 2;
    private int mode = NONE;
    // remember some things for zooming
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();
    private float oldDist = 1f;
    private float d = 0f;
    private float newRot = 0f;
    private float[] lastEvent = null;
    private ImageView view, fin;
    private Bitmap bmap;
FrameLayout frm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        fin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);
frm=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frm);

    }
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // handle touch events here
        view = (ImageView) v;
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                d = rotation(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    if (lastEvent != null && event.getPointerCount() == 2 || event.getPointerCount() == 3) {
                        newRot = rotation(event);
                        float r = newRot - d;
                        float[] values = new float[9];
                        matrix.getValues(values);
                        float tx = values[2];
                        float ty = values[5];
                        float sx = values[0];
                        float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                        float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                        matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        view.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

        bmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmap);
        view.draw(canvas);

        //fin.setImageBitmap(bmap);
        return true;
    }


    public void ButtonClick(View v){

        fin.setImageBitmap(bmap);
    }
    /**
     * Determine the space between the first two fingers
     */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        float s=x * x + y * y;
        return (float)Math.sqrt(s);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
     */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the degree to be rotated by.
     *
     * @param event
     * @return Degrees
     */
    private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
        double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
        return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
    }
}
```

-> Try this.